# Unable to connect to Azure SQL database from my ASP.NET Core Web API application but able to connect to db from Management Studio

Tags: c#, azure-sql-database, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to connect to my Azure SQL database from a ASP.NET Core Web API application. Though I am able to successfully connect to azure db with same credential from SQL Server Management Studio, I keep getting this error:

> Cannot open database '', requested by the login'. The login failed. Login failed for user ''

Here is the connection string in my `appsettings.json`:

```
"DatabaseConfiguration": {
    "ConnectionString": "Server=tcp:xxx.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=back-end-sqldb;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=<userid>;Password=<pwd>;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
}
```

I also tried with

```
"ConnectionString": "Data Source=server.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=enrolment--back-end-sqldb;User ID=<userid>;Password=<password>;"
```

Can anyone help me how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Are Sql Management studio and Web API on same machine or different machine  ? Another thing is in error message does it give you any username or it is just blank ?

Comment: yes, SqlManagement studio and webapi on the same machine. The error message contains the 'username'

Comment: Try with Persist Security Info=True.
Also here is same question .https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/102605/azure-sql-database-login-failed-for-user-in-application-but-works-fine-in-ssm

Answer (score 0):

It worked, when i tried the following connection string with servername along with userid i.e

```
"ConnectionString": "Data Source=server.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=sqldb;User ID=<userid@server.database.windows.net>;Password=<pwd>;"
```